# How to create a new flutter project with the same app signing and id of an old project?

Tags: android, ios, flutter

I have an old Flutter project that was written about 3 years ago and already published on Play Store and App Store, I want to revamp the whole app code, features and structure and update it to the same published app, however I feel it will be better to recreate the project from scratch with the new Flutter and dart versions and new packages and so on.
So is it possible to recreate a new Flutter project on Android Studio while keeping the same app keys and ids for Play and App Store?

Comment: yes it is. jsut keep the identifier same.

Comment: But does that make sure the it has the same signing key for the app bundle?

Comment: you have the signing keys right? It's your job to make sure that you uses existing keys